# Sort dataframe columns by month and year

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I am looking at monthly data, in a data frame. The column headers are all string, converted from datetime. This is my final output thus far:

```
                             Feb 18  Jan 18  Mar 18
Flavor                                                      
Vanilla                      16.0    10.0     0.0
Chocolate                    20.0    20.0    16.0
```

Seems that the columns are sorted alphabetically. Is there a way I can sort these columns of type string by month AND year? Does it involve using prefixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn your column names to datetime, and then sort them:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%b %y')

df = df[sorted(df.columns)]

>>> df
           2018-01-01  2018-02-01  2018-03-01
Flavor                                       
Vanilla          10.0        16.0         0.0
Chocolate        20.0        20.0        16.0
```

If you want your original string column names back simply add:

```
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%b %y')

>>> df
           Jan 18  Feb 18  Mar 18
Flavor                           
Vanilla      10.0    16.0     0.0
Chocolate    20.0    20.0    16.0
```

An alternative is to do it all in one line using `sorted` with a key (credit to @SpghttCd for the idea):

```
df[sorted(df.columns, key = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b %y'))]
```

Comment: Most likely, OP does not want to change the original names, so it would be more straight forward to use the `key` parameter of `sorted`: `df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%b %y'))]`

Comment: You could do something like that (I'll add it to my answer), but it's quite a bit less readable in my opinion. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, but to address readability, you could easily store the key first in an extra array and then redefine the dataframe: `mykey=pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%b %y')`, `df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=mykey)]`

Comment: Good to know. @sacul However, I cannot agree with my suggestion would be "all that in one line", it is not at all: you rename the columns of OPs df, sort it, and rename the columns back. I just sort, just telling the sorting algorithm which rule it should use. Just think of someone, who wanted to sort by length of column titles - how would you try to rename that back...?

Comment: @sacul completely OK, thanks for clarifying - but I didn't feel offended nor missed any credits. I'm just discussing about algorithms/solutions for a certain problem.

Comment: The point is, that by using the key parameter of sorted, you do not "do _all_ of it in one line". Because what you leave away is twice renaming the dataframe's column titles. So three things, which I find important here; 1. it's more efficient, because less to do for the computer. 2. It does not touch the data (it's metadata here, but you know what I mean) 3. It's generalizable to other order rules (you can rename titles into `len(title)` - but you'll never get back to `title` again.)

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for your input! You're right, it is more efficient

Answer (score 2):

You can use, make a dict where keys would be original column names and values would be their `datetime` objects and then sort that dict by value, only to order it and then get the desired df.

```
import operator
sorted_dict = sorted(dict(zip(df.columns,pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%b %y'))).items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
df[[i[0] for i in sorted_dict]]
```

Output:

```
           Jan 18   Feb 18  Mar 18
Flavor          
Vanilla    10.0     16.0    0.0
Chocolate  20.0     20.0    16.0
```